# How to include different .aar depending on the android build variant

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am having 3 .aar files which are included in a module and the aar module in included in a **app** module.

Currently I have 3 build variants and for specific build variant I want to include specific aar.

Lets Suppose:
I have 3 aars naming
xyz, pqr, def

xyz to be included in 123 build variant
pqr to be included in 456 build variant
def to be included in 789 build variant

**aar module build.gradle**

```
File xyzFile= file("xyz.aar")
File pqrFile = file("pqr.aar")
File defFile = file("def.aar")


configurations.maybeCreate("xyz")
   artifacts.add("xyz", xyzFile)
configurations.maybeCreate("pqr")
 artifacts.add("pqr", pqrFile )
configurations.maybeCreate("def")
    artifacts.add("def", defFile )
```

**app project build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

configurations {
    xyzDebugCompile
    xyzReleaseCompile
    xyzReleaseUnsignedCompile

    pqrDebugCompile
    pqrReleaseCompile
    pqrReleaseUnsignedCompile

    defDebugCompile
    defReleaseCompile
    defReleaseUnsignedCompile

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
   =

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cm.ez.eia"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName '0.9.2'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    project.ext { appName = 'FA-Comm' }
                    def newName = output.outputFile.name
                    newName = newName.replace("app-", "$project.ext.appName-")
                    output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newName)
                }
            }

        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    project.ext { appName = 'FA-Comm' }
                    def newName = output.outputFile.name
                    newName = newName.replace("app-", "$project.ext.appName-")
                    output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newName)
                }
            }

            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        releaseUnsigned {
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    project.ext { appName = 'FA-Comm' }
                    def newName = output.outputFile.name
                    newName = newName.replace("app-", "$project.ext.appName-")
                    output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newName)
                }
            }
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "1g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
        preDexLibraries = false //delete the already predexed libraries
    }


    productFlavors {
        xyz {
            applicationId 'com.fieldaware.communicator'
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 24
        }


        def {
            applicationId 'com.fieldaware.communicator'
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 24
        }
        pqr {
            applicationId 'com.fieldaware.communicator'
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 24
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':android-common-master')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'



    //Aar Configs
    xyzDebugCompile project(path:':sdk',configuration: 'xyz')
    xyzReleaseCompile project(path:':sdk',configuration: 'xyz')
    xyzReleaseUnsignedCompile project(path:':sdk',configuration: 'xyz')


    pqrDebugCompile project(path: ':sdk', configuration: 'pqr')
    pqrReleaseCompile project(path: ':sdk', configuration: 'pqr')
    pqrReleaseUnsignedCompile project(path: ':sdk', configuration: 'pqr')

    defDebugCompile project(path: ':sdk', configuration: 'def')
    defReleaseCompile project(path: ':sdk', configuration: 'def')
    defReleaseUnsignedCompile project(path: ':sdk', configuration: 'def')
}
```

I want to include the specific .aar file according to the specific build variant.

This code is fetching incorrect aar files. Please suggest any solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I am answering my own question because anyone faces same thing then there is proper solution available.

First of all: **You cannot include 3 aars in a library project and choose them accordingly as of now I am using Android Studio 2.2.3**

My approach to include 3 aars was.

I have created 3 library modules in my main application naming:

settings.gradle

```
include ':xyzaar', ':pqraar', ':defaar',...
```

`xyzaar` directory will include `xyz.aar` file

xyzaar-> build.gradle

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('xyz.aar'))
```

Same as for other 2 cars

app-> build.gradle

```
xyzDebugCompile project(path: ':xyzaar')
xyzReleaseCompile project(path: ':xyzaar')
xyzReleaseUnsignedCompile project(path: ':xyzaar')

pqrDebugCompile project(path: ':pqraar')
pqrReleaseCompile project(path: ':pqraar')
pqrReleaseUnsignedCompile project(path: ':pqraar')

defDebugCompile project(path: ':defaar')
defReleaseCompile project(path: ':defaar')
defReleaseUnsignedCompile project(path: ':defaar')
```

Thanks
P.S: This approach works for me very good and app doesn't include unwanted aar files

Answer (score 1):

In your app build.gradle add the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    ...
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    } 
} 
...
```

drop you *.aar files into this libs directory and add the following to your app build.gradle:

```
xyzDebugCompile(name: 'xyz', ext: 'aar')
xyzReleaseCompile(name: 'xyz', ext: 'aar')
xyzReleaseUnsignedCompile(name: 'xyz', ext: 'aar')

pqrDebugCompile(name: 'pqr', ext: 'aar')
pqrReleaseCompile(name: 'pqr', ext: 'aar')
pqrReleaseUnsignedCompile(name: 'pqr', ext: 'aar')

defDebugCompile(name: 'def', ext: 'aar')
defReleaseCompile(name: 'def', ext: 'aar')
defReleaseUnsignedCompile(name: 'def', ext: 'aar')
```

Comment: But I guess 3 aar will always be included in app source code. with this solution?

Comment: Nope. only one aar will be included. Reason being that 'xyz, 'pqr' and 'def' are your build flavors and 'debug', 'release' and 'releaseUnsigned' are your build variants. If you run './gradlew assemble' you will get nine apk's outputed; one for each build variant/flavor combination. And each apk will only contain one of the aar (the appropriate one for that build variant/flavor).  
To help better explain it: if you run './gradlew assembleXyzDebugCompile' it will generate the apk for that one (of nine) build variant/flavor and that apk will compile with only the one xyz.aar

Comment: Thanks @Jason.. I have created a 3 seperate modules with 3 different aars and included accordingly in flavor

Comment: "First of all: You cannot include 3 aars in a library project and choose them accordingly" Same thing in AS 3.X.X :( I thought I could do that without creating separate modules but that was not the case

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer, if you want to add a dependency for a variant that combines **a product flavor and a build type**, then you must initialize the configuration name in the configurations block.
The following sample adds a runtimeOnly dependency to your "freeDebug" build variant (using a local binary dependency):

```
configurations {
    // Initializes a placeholder for the freeDebugRuntimeOnly dependency
    // configuration.
    freeDebugRuntimeOnly {}
}

dependencies {
    freeDebugRuntimeOnly fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```